# Error: cannot find symbol import androidx.navigation.fragment.navArgs

Tags: java, android

I was doing the "Build Your First Android App in Java" from the website https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/build-your-first-android-app/#8.
Everything worked until I got to step 8, which was to import androidx.navigation.fragment.navArgs, but I got an error:

import androidx.navigation.fragment.**navArgs**;

How do I fix it? What does it mean?

Answer (score 5):

This is an error with the codelab, pulled in from the [Kotlin version of the code lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/build-your-first-android-app-kotlin/#8) which uses the `by navArgs()` Kotlin property delegate to retrieve the arguments (as explained in the [Using Safe Args guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args)).

This isn't needed in Java, as you use the `SecondFragmentArgs.fromBundle(getArguments())` method to retrieve the arguments class.

Therefore, you can just skip that import: it isn't used anywhere and can safely be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

if you are following [building your first app in java](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/build-your-first-android-app#8) and you encountered this error,than try **commenting** or **deleting** following import

```
import androidx.navigation.fragment.navArgs;
```

Comment: adding details or reference of what it is and why it will work if removed will help others to understand it better

Answer (score 0):

You have two *build.gradle* in your build scripts section. One of them is your project wide file and the other is your module one.

In your project one, you have to have this line inside your *depencies*:

```
    dependencies {

        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.0-alpha04"
    }
```

in your other file, the build.gradle that is for your module, you have to add this following line (it is usually on top of it with the other lines alike):

```
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
```

On other note, as you are starting to learn, I strongly recommend that you learn Kotlin instead of Java. Kotlin is the newly Google supported language to develop Android Apps.

Let me know if it fixes your issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question, I appreciate it. However, I still have the same error:

C:\Users\oesco\AndroidStudioProjects\MyFirstApp\app\src\main\java\com\example\myfirstapp\SecondFragment.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
import androidx.navigation.fragment.navArgs;
                                   ^
  symbol:   class navArgs

Answer (score -1):

This is an error with the Java tutorial because of the newer Android Studio versions, on the Kotlin one, it doesn't give you that problems.

try to go to the "SecondFragment.java" file and add this in the line:
@SuppressLint("StringFormatInvalid" //line that evades the formatting problem.

before the `onViewCreated` method, so it would end like this:

```
@SuppressLint("StringFormatInvalid")
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    Integer count = SecondFragmentArgs.fromBundle(getArguments()).getMyArg();
    String countText = getString(R.string.random_heading, count);
    TextView headerView = view.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.textview_header);
    headerView.setText(countText);
    Random random = new java.util.Random();
    Integer randomNumber = 0;

    if (count > 0) {
        randomNumber = random.nextInt(count + 1);
    }

    TextView randomView = view.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.textview_random);
    randomView.setText(randomNumber.toString());

    view.findViewById(R.id.button_second).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            NavHostFragment.findNavController(SecondFragment.this)
                    .navigate(R.id.action_SecondFragment_to_FirstFragment);
        }
    });
```

All the other code after that line I told you is the same as the tutorial (I put it just in case tho), hope it helps ;).