# building my first app with codelabs having some trouble

Tags: java, android-studio, class, google-codelab

I am starting to learn java and use the android studio app to create my own application but after I did all the steps the final step is not working and the app is given me an error "cannot find symbol class navArgs' in the first and the second fragment.java
can you please check the code since I was just copying it and pasting without any changes
the error is in task 9 step 7[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jm6wZ.png)

Comment: The answer to your question is posted on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62110020/12502168).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete

```
import androidx.navigation.fragment.navArgs;
```

change dependencies from build.gradle(Module:)

```
dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3"
        def nav_version = "2.3.5"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
```

change count initialization to

```
Integer count = SecondFragmentArgs.fromBundle(getArguments()).getMyarg();
```

(small A in getMyarg())